# Eclipse cannot detect Lenovo P770 in Windows 8

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, detection

I've been at this for quite some time already, and have not found a fix yet, so any insight would be great.

First off, I've tried installing the USB drivers from here (Lenovo OEM site): http://developer.lenovomm.com/developer/driverprogram.jsp

I've also tried updating the drivers from \extras\google\usb_driver but I always get an error indicating that it could not find the drivers.

Windows can actually detect the device, but it has this warning icon over the device name.

I think that this is possibly a driver issue, but I'm not quite sure. I've tried using different ways to connect to my Laptop, (USB Storage, MTP, PTP) but it still doesn't work. USB debugging on the device has also been checked.

I've tried using PDANet+ and MoboRobo to force a connection but still nothing. I've tried searching (and am still searching) for solutions, and I hope that some of you guys can offer other ways to get around this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please, where can i find the USB drivers Lenovo OEM ? i find nothing on  http://developer.lenovomm.com/developer/driverprogram.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Try this one out:

"If your A3000 is like my UK spec A3000, a rash assumption given what we know about Lenovo's policy for multiple firmware for the same hardware, anyway, go to Settings, Storage, there should be a three dot icon in the upper right, tap it, you should get a "USB computer connection" option, tap that, you should get a page of options as to how your USB connect works when you connect to a PC. The last option is to appear as a CDROM to the PC. The software on the CDROM are the ADB drivers for connecting to the A3000 for debug. I found this by accident, certainly Lenovo didn't tell me."

I found that from a lenovo forum. It worked on my Ideapad Yoga 10 (B8000-F).

Answer (score 2):

i know exactly what your problem is. I am a Lenovo P770 user also. I manage to connect it with Eclipse. Just follow my steps:-
 1. Connect your P770 to your PC as USB Storage(Connect to USB Storage).
 2. Find folder ideatool and copy file LenovoUsbDriver_1.0.1.exe and paste it in your PC.
 3. Disconnect your device and Install LenovoUsbDriver_1.0.1.exe and then restart PC.
 4. Connect again your device to your PC as a USB Storage again instead of MTP/PTP.
 5. In Eclipse, on the menu bar,click Run->Run Configurations. Click target tab and choose 'Always Prompt to Pick Device'.
 6. Apply and Run. Now, you can see your device is listed in the 'Choose a running Android device'.
 7. done.

Comment: i could not find LenovoUsbDriver_1.0.1.exe on the device, i downloaded it from this link http://www.mediafire.com/download/ggstttf5xtnozvd/LenovoUsbDriver_v1.0.14.zip